# issues using external components with nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new to nuxt and I started using it together with `vuetify`.
Actually I wanted to implement a Google Places Autocomplete and I have found this: [vuetify-google-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-google-autocomplete). It looks very nice and easy to implement. But it doesn't.

What I did is to follow exactly the documentation.

I created a file called `google-autocomplete.js` in the `plugins` folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VuetifyGoogleAutocomplete from 'vuetify-google-autocomplete'

Vue.use(VuetifyGoogleAutocomplete, {
  apiKey: 'MY_KEY'
})
```

In the `nuxt.config.js` I registered it like that:

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/vuetify', '@/plugins/google-autocomplete'],
```

Finally in my `.vue` file I did:

```
<template>
  <vuetify-google-autocomplete
    id="map"
    append-icon="search"
    disabled="true"
    placeholder="Start typing"
    @placechanged="getAddressData"
  ></vuetify-google-autocomplete>
</teamplate>
```

Down in the `script` section I created a test method:

```
methods: {
  getAddressData: (addressData, placeResultData, id) => {
    console.log(addressData, placeResultData, id)
  }
}
```

The result is that nothing work! :D
What I'm getting is:

```
SyntaxError
Unexpected identifier
Missing stack frames
...etc...
```

I tried to play with the `nuxt.config.js`, setting the plugin `ssr` to `false`. It doesn't fail like that, it load the page but there are tons of other issues related to `vuetify` components not loaded.

What I wanted to understand is how should I use these plugins/components in a nuxt project. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add `transpile` build option since `vuetify-google-autocomplete` use ES6 module. Please see [ES6 plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#es6-plugins) for more about detail.

So your `nuxt.config.js` should be:

```
export default {
  build: {
    transpile: ['google-autocomplete']
  },
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/vuetify',
    '@/plugins/google-autocomplete'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of above, if you are facing this while writing your own plugin with a dependency to an external package. You could choose to write a Nuxt module instead of a plugin. This way you can add the plugin code and transpile settings in one go instead of manually adding this (and potentially forget) to `nuxt.config.js`